# r Shiny: issue filtering data using checkboxes

Tags: r, shiny

In my shiny app, I am using checkboxes to filter my data.  Consider the example where I have a dataframe with sets and colours: set 1 contains red and yellow colours, set 2 contains only the colour red and set 3 contains only the colour yellow.

When I filter my data by the colours red and yellow at the moment, it returns the set2 (only contains red), set 3(only contains yellow) and set1 that contains both.  However, my desired output would be that picking red and yellow would only return the group that contains both colours (set1).

I want the returned group to exactly match my checkbox selection.
i.e. checking just red would return the group that only contains red, checking just yellow would return the group that only contains yellow and checking red and yellow returns the group that contains red and yellow.

The code for this example (this is a simplified version of my app) is as follows:

My server:

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  data <- structure(list(Set = c("Set1", "Set1", "Set1", "Set2", "Set2", 
                             "Set2", "Set3", "Set3", "Set3", "Set4"), Colour = c("red", "red", 
                                                                                 "yellow", "red", "red", "red", "yellow", "yellow", "yellow", 
                                                                                 "blue")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))

  output$choose_colour <- renderUI({

    colour.names <- as.vector( unique(data$Colour ))

    checkboxGroupInput("colours", "Choose Colours to Include", 
                       choices  = colour.names)
  })

  model.data <- reactive({

    filtered_data <- data %>% group_by(Set) %>% filter(all(Colour%in% input$colours))
    filtered_data

  })

  output$filteredData <- renderDataTable({
    filtered_data <- model.data()
    filtered_data
  })

})
```

My ui:

```
ui <- fluidPage(


 mainPanel(
  uiOutput('choose_colour'),
  
 
  dataTableOutput('filteredData')
  
)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I switched the order around and changed any for all

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(purrr)
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  
  data <- structure(list(Set = c("Set1", "Set1", "Set1", "Set2", "Set2", 
                                 "Set2", "Set3", "Set3", "Set3", "Set4"), Colour = c("red", "red", 
                                                                                     "yellow", "red", "red", "red", "yellow", "yellow", "yellow", 
                                                                                     "blue")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
  
  output$choose_colour <- renderUI({
    
    colour.names <- as.vector( unique(data$Colour ))
    
    checkboxGroupInput("colours", "Choose Colours to Include", 
                       choices  = colour.names)
  })
  
  model.data <- reactive({
    
    filtered_data <- data %>% group_by(Set) %>% filter(all(Colour %in% input$colours) & all(input$colours %in%Colour))
    filtered_data
    
  })
  
  output$filteredData <- renderDataTable({
    filtered_data <- model.data()
    filtered_data
  })
  
})

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  
  mainPanel(
    uiOutput('choose_colour'),
    
    
    dataTableOutput('filteredData')
    
  )
)

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Comment: I would like my returned data to exactly match the filters from the checkboxes. i.e. if I select red, then it returns the group that only contains red.  If I select yellow, then it returns the group that only contains yellow.  If I select red and yellow, then it returns the group containing red and yellow

Comment: Tried to flip it around, but ended up exactly as you had before

Comment: Solved it by checking in both directions, your question would have been much simpler if it wasn't on a shiny app